# When is a batch REST transaction better than lots of individual transactions?

Tags: rest, transaction

We are building a REST API which creates items in a CDN.  Each item takes between 5 and 7 seconds to create, and we need to create them as quickly as possible until we have about a million of them.

One school of thought in our office is that we should make lots of small transactions.  Another is that we should have fewer, larger transactions to minimise network "chat", perhaps running as described [here](http://farazdagi.com/blog/2014/rest-long-running-jobs/).

Small transactions would be simpler to implement.  They would involve a bit more network traffic (perhaps insignificant given the time per item).  They could also be advantageous in the event of a failure to create an item.

Performance is our top priority, development cost a close second.  [This post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/229042/does-a-batch-of-operations-violate-rest-principles) suggests that either is OK in principle.  Which/how do I choose?

---

Our CDN will serve up images of properties in New Zealand.  We will pre-populate the CDN with six images of each property we think is likely to be requested.  The different images are used by various pages in our website.

The image generation process looks like this:

```
for each property {
    call remote 3rd-party API to find property details;
    for each type of image required {
        call remote 3rd-party API to get image;
    }
}
```

The remote API calls each take between 1 and 2 seconds.  The remote API is on the opposite side of the planet to our users and our servers.  The stuff that happens locally is in the millisecond range.  I'm using C# `async` where possible.

If somebody requests an image that isn't already cached in the CDN, it generally comes back in two or three seconds, which is acceptable.  We load it with AJAX too, so the user isn't kept waiting.

Comment: This is a one-time execution, right?  7 million seconds is about 81 days.

Comment: We need more input on where you lose time and also how much tasks you can handle in parallel since that 81 days should not be your aim I guess. So is the delay in your rest api itself or is it the work done after the request? Also: rest is protocol agnostic. So if http has too much overhead you could upgrade to another protocol when support by the other party, not used very often, as example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873247/is-http-status-code-426-upgrade-required-only-meant-signal-an-upgrade-to-a-secur

Comment: @Robert, It's a bit like painting a house: you paint it all when it's first built, then you have to patch bits as you go along.  We may find we need to repaint patches before we've finished painting the whole house, but that would merely affect batch composition.

Comment: @Luc, we're actually OK with 81 days - not overjoyed, but meh, OK. This process merely pre-populates our CDN with what we think is likely to be requested.  We can also generate it on-the-fly if it's not already there when requested.  On-the-fly performance is acceptable - we just want to make it better. The delay is mostly in a third party API on the other side of the planet. Their servers are probably better at parallel than ours. Good call to consider parallel.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "on-the-fly performance is acceptable, we just want to _pre-populate the CDN to_ make it better".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your update what you could do is the following:

Work with queues

**Initial population:**

```
for each property {
    insert job in queue 1 to handle property
}
```

**queue 1**

```
call remote 3rd-party API to find property details;

    for each type of image required {
        insert job in queue 2 to get image
    }
```

**queue 2**

```
call remote 3rd-party API to get image;
```

**Implementation options**

You should be able to do this quite simple with some standard queue software. It will be parallel and handles errors etcetera. That will take down your process time considerable and keeps your code quite simple.

And example could be: https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/ but there are many more. Some example could be this: https://startupnextdoor.com/adding-to-sqs-queue-using-aws-lambda-and-a-serverless-api-endpoint/ then you would use Lambda which is quite nice for this kind of jobs because it scales nicely.

The nice thing about an existing queue package is also that it will help you with retries on failure etc. So that reduces the amount of logic to be written.

**Performance**

You can manage the amount of jobs within the queue en scale the workers to find an optimal fit. You might also not want to overrun the supplier of the data by too many requests. **Talk with them** before you start hitting them with lots of requests.

Performance here is practically unlimited, AWS will scale incredible likely stronger than your supplier if their requests take so long.

**Alternatives**

Clearly you can do this with any kind of queue software. You just should ensure that you feed the properties list once. If you want an object to update you could feed it again and it will process it again and get the new images for example with the same code.

**Delay**

If you have setup as above your only further improvement would be to find out why it takes so damn long to handle the requests. But I suppose that the above will make it less relevant.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion Luc. I'm currently implementing .NET Parallel.ForEach. I'll post again when I've figured out if it helps. In the meantime, I guess then you would suggest batches rather than individual transactions?

Comment: I ended up following Stephen Cleary's answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallell-foreach) for parallelism. A batch of 10 properties now completes in 10 seconds, compared to 120 seconds when processed sequentially (the scope of processing each property grew a bit).  So that's a big improvement.

Comment: Good to hear you found a faster solution!

Answer (score 0):

A good test is worth a thousand expert opinions.

Each item takes 7 seconds to create when doing it which way?

Different ways of doing it slow you down differently.  Doing batches may speed things up but until you try you don't really know.

Test doing 10.  Then 100. Then 1000.  Time it and find out if this is even linear.

Now you should have enough data to make the call.

If that's still to painful find out why it's taking 7 seconds.  And what's taking the most time.  There is almost always a way to make it faster.  Focus on what's taking the bulk of the time.  Don't guess at this.

Comment: 7 seconds as part of a batch of 10.  We've already optimised the process for each property.  We're making several calls per property to an API in another continent.  The slowness is almost all in those API calls, and we've rationalised them as best we can.  We might see if we can run up an Azure server closer to the source API and drag the generated data back in chunks.